# Install Project for C# and Azure SQL

Tags: c#, azure, installation, azure-sql-database, setup-project

I have C# application that uses SQL Database (Local). I managed data layer with SQL Server 2014 and SSMS on my computer. That local database has a sync rule with Azure SQL and use Microsoft SQL Data Sync Agent Preview. Now I need these:

1- I need a Setup File for the application. I know how to create Setup Project with VS2013 for a normal client application but this will be different I suppose. This setup file must contain SQL Compact Edition 4.0 and Microsoft SQL Data Sync Agent Preview setup file.

2- During installation, Installer must check whether SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 is installed on client computer. If not, it should prompt.

3- I have Database Creation Scripts and after installation of SQL Server CE, I need these scripts should run and create database and database objects which application will use.

4- Now comes the tricky part. I need Microsoft SQL Data Sync Agent Preview installed on target computer. Because the client's local database should have the sync rule with Azure. I have no idea how to do that with installation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately SQL CE is not supported by SQL Data Sync service.  SQL Data Sync supports SQL Server 2005 SP2 and above.  Please refer to the "system requirements" page of the MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127278.aspx:

SQL Server 2005 SP2. 
SQL Data Sync (Preview) works best with SQL Server 2008 R2 and later as support for SQL Database was added to SQL Server Management Studio in SQL Server 2008 R2. If you do not have SQL Server 2008 R2 you can download a free trial from SQL Server 2012 trial or a trial of SQL Server 2008 R2. 
SQL Data Sync (Preview) currently supports only SQL Server and SQL Database. Express versions of SQL Server are not supported.